# GetTime function not working NodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am using getTime() to get seconds from date in nodejs with Mongoose. Datatype of parameter is as `Date` in schema. And I want to compare that with another time which is in seconds of 24 hours. Here is my code :

```
Schema datatype - 
 eventDateTime: Date
```

Here is the function code

```
          EventModal.getAllEvent(function (eventResp) {
                            if (Object.keys(eventResp).length > 0) { 
 console.log('eventResp.eventDateTime',eventResp.eventDateTime.getTime());
                                if (eventResp.eventDateTime.getTime() < 86400) {
                                     // do something 
                                    });
                                }
                            }
                        });
```

I want to compare time in if condition. Please check and let me know where I have done wrong. 
Thank you !

Comment: Damini Is there any error which are you getting?

Comment: Yes , getting error  `Cannot read property 'getTime' of undefined.`
But i am getting data in console

Comment: where you have consoled the data in your code. please edit.

Comment: Edited in question

Comment: can you please update what is the value which are you getting using console ?

Comment: This error is showing because your eventResp Object doesn't have eventDateTime property. Just log it and you will see.

Comment: its values is as `2017-12-07T11:18:19.549Z`

Comment: what is the `typeof(eventResp.eventDateTime)`

Comment: I think you would have to do `new Date(eventResp.eventDateTime).getTime() < 86400`

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that some event doesn't contain an eventDateTime property. Or that the property `eventDateTime` doesn't have a `getTime()` which means that its not instanceof Date. So try to make all the necessary checks before accessing inner objects.

```
EventModal.getAllEvent(function(eventResp) {

    if (Object.keys(eventResp).length > 0) {

        if ( eventResp && eventResp.eventDateTime && eventResp.eventDateTime instanceof Date &&  eventResp.eventDateTime.getTime() < 86400) {

            // do something 

        }
        else{
            //do nothing or log
            console.log("No event date.") //for event: eventResp.name  bla bla
            // or you could log the eventResp to check what it has inside
            console.log(eventResp)
        }
    }
});
```